# Group Number in a LINQ Group by Query

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I've been using [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) to get my feet wet using LINQ. It's been a good first resource, but I can't see an example there of what I currently need.

I just need to associate a sequential group number with each group. I have a working solution:

```
var groups =
   from c in list
   group c by c.Name into details
   select new { Name = details.Key, DetailRecords = details };


int groupNumber = 0;
foreach (var group in groups)
{
   // 
   // process each group and it's records ...
   // 

   groupNumber++;
}
```

But, I'm sure it's possible to use LINQ to also generate the groupNumber. How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on your exact needs, but you can use:

```
var groupArray = groups.ToArray();
```

Similarly, you can use `ToList`. These data structures are sequential, and each group has an index.

---

If you do need the index on the object you create, another option is to use `Select`:

```
list.GroupBy(c => c.Name)
    .Select((details, ind) =>
    new
    {
        Name = details.Key,
        DetailRecords = details,
        Index = ind
    });
```

Comment: There are two answers here. I like the ToList solution, but the two parameter select was exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem. In a way, it means you have an index on any `IEnumerable`, but as I've said, it depends on your needs whether it should be in every object or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

this should do the trick:

```
int groupNumber = 0;
var groups =
   from c in list
   group c by c.Name into details
   select new { Name = details.Key, DetailRecords = details, grpNum = groupNumber++};
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's just a sequential group number, just use the Count() method on your IEnumerable.

```
var groups =
   from c in list
   group c by c.Name into details
   select new {Name = details.Key, DetailRecords = details};

for(int i = 0; i < groups.Count(); i++)
{
  //Process Records
}
```

Then, if you need the specific group number, you can just grab `i`.

Comment: Like my original solution, but cleaner in that the increment won't get  lost in the processing code.